# How to avoid function repetition in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery and currently working on [www.image.cards](https://image.cards), a tool for learning Dutch.

Click an image to reveal the Dutch word and click the music note to play an audio file revealing the pronunciation.

These music notes have their own id's (id='horse') and the mp3 files their own names (./mp3/horse.mp3).

This is my HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front"><img src="/img/horse.png"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>Horse</p><b id="horse">♫</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And I am using jQuery as follows:

```
$("#horse").click(function () { 
    var horse = new Audio("./mp3/horse.mp3"); 
    horse.play(); 
});
```

I'm currently adding a function for every single card. I don't mind but I feel there is a smarter way to do this since the button-id and the mp3 files have the same name.

Perhaps copy and paste the name of an 'id' to the .mp3 somehow?

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
var $this = $(this);
    $('.back b[name="'+$this.attr('id')+'"]', .play("./mp3/'$this'.mp3");
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Every day is a school day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the common selector for all those clickable elements.

As apparently all are `b` elements that are children of a `div` element that has class `back`, you can do this:

```
$(".back>b").click(function(){
    new Audio("./mp3/" + this.id + ".mp3").play();
});
```

Note that `$(this).attr("id")` will evaluate to the same as `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<section>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front"><img src="/img/horse.png"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>Horse</p><b class="play-controller" data-sound="./mp3/horse.mp3">♫</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And in your js code:

```
$('.play-controller').on('click', function() {
  const sound = new Audio($(this).data('sound')); 
  sound.play();
});
```